# PyPDF2 TypeError when trying to run example from lib

Tags: python, python-3.x, pypdf

I've got PyPDF2 lib from here:
https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2/tree/Python3-3

When trying to run script "Example 1:" from from there see it:

```
PyPDF2 python versions (2.5 - 3.3) compatibility branch

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "1.py", line 6, in <module>
    input1 = PdfFileReader(open("document1.pdf", "rb"))
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\pdf.py", line 595, in __init__
    self.read(stream)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\pdf.py", line 1097, in read
    streamData = StringIO(xrefstream.getData())
TypeError: initial_value must be str or None, not bytes
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Did you finally find the solution to this error?

Comment: no, i can't find the solution(

Comment: possible duplicate of [pyPDF2 TypeError when trying to extract text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17270387/pypdf2-typeerror-when-trying-to-extract-text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a problem related to the compatibility within PyPDF2 and Python 3.

In my case, I have solved it by replacing pdf.py and utils.py with the ones you will find here, where they basically control if you are running Python 3 and, in case you are, receive data as bytes instead of strings.